# Want to test Sending tokens from one chain to another using wormhole but on testnet

Tags: solidity, sepolia

I am really not sure how to get started with this , we barely have tokens on testnet and most of them are created, using wormhole I want to be able to send tokens from one chain to another. Also if possible create my tokens and send it from one chain to another. In order to receive on the other chain I guess we need to create a wrapped version of it. And I am not sure as to how to do it.